# Artifactory - audit info on binaries

Tags: jenkins, gitlab-ci, artifactory, audit

We are looking to do a Gitlab / Jenkins - Artifactory CI setup. A query on audit information came up.

What audit trail of builds is available in Artifactory to demonstrate to audit teams the link between a build that ran on Gitlan / Jenkins linking it to a particular binary that was stored in an Artifactory repo? Does Artifactory keep tracking info on the binaries pushed to it by Gitlab CI / Jenkins?

I hope I was able to frame my query correctly. Please feel free to ask if I need to clarify further.

Comment: Very broad question, better to raise it to vendor JFrog for version specific information,

Comment: I looked up the [JFrog support website](https://jfrog.com/support/). They appear to be hosting the customer ticket portal only now. And pointing to SO for the JFrog User Q&A Community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That kind of audit trail may not be available in Artifactory, you need to build this `traceability` across tools as per your organization requirements. If `Jenkins` is the CI engine and responsible for creating the build, in the job configuration you will find that a `version` parameter can be created. You can create a very specific version for each `build artifact` for example `branchname+jenkinsjobname+timestamp` and you will get an output file `concatenatedstring_timestamp.jar` and this will be pushed into `Artifactory` with a specific non-human `user` which is already integrated between the two applications. In Artifactory you will be able to see which user pushed the artifact. And when this `concatenatedstring` is seen in Artifactory by an audit team, they will also be able to see a unique `branchname` and `jenkins job name` with a `timestamp` which provides the `traceability` as per audit requirements.

This `tracebility` needs to be built in scenarios when we do not use the same tool for all operations. For example if you used `GitLab` itself for SCM, CI and Artifact Management within the same product, `traceability` comes OOTB.